# pdf compressor on Win 7

Tags: pdf, compression

I would like to know a preferably free software to compress PDFs on Win 7 so that I can email them. I came across [this one](http://www.cvisiontech.com/products/general/pdfcompressor-information.html?lang=eng), but it requested that I enable User Access Control so I am a bit wary.

Comment: Why not compress/archive them with something like winrar or 7zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [PdfCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) to "print" it. you can define with how many dpi you print or with how many colors or if you want to convert the images to greyscale etc.